# How to detect if a textbox has .com or any other url extensions?

Tags: c#, wpf, http, .net-4.0, browser

I want to make it so you can use search on the `WebBrowser` Address Bar but I need to make it so it can detect .com, .org, .gov, .jp, .de, .us, etc. But, I can't seem to figure out how. Since the new release of html you can have whatever `URL` extension you want.

Comment: Why do you need to detect these? The whole point of the `WebBrowser` control is it already has web browsing functionality built in.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Uri`? 

It can parse URL strings for you.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: Ya I tryed but it didn't work...

Comment: What exactly didn't work?  Stack Overflow is here to help you with code you've already written, not to write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the domain with the following code:

```
var match = Regex.Match(
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658387/how-to-detect-if-a-textbox-has-com-or-anyother-url-extentions",
    "//.*?(\\.[^./]+)(/|$)"
);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

However, this will only extract the last part after the dot. So, `"http://mysite.co.uk"` will result in `".uk"`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it once I compile my browser components together.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to do this on the page itself:

```
 if ($("#mytxtbox").val().indexOf('.com') != -1) {
       alert("We have .com in our name. Alert the Americans.");
 };
```

-1 = not found

any other number = position of the character in the array of letters.

In C# the idea is similar, but then you can do:

```
if (myString.Contains(".com")) 
    Console.WriteLine("We have .com in our name. Alert the Americans.");
```

Comment: Ya but I want it to detect all url extentions.